# Flutter: Dynamic Persistent Bottom Nav

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm using Flutter and Firebase. In my Flutter App, I'm using the *persistent_bottom_nav_bar* package from Flutter. I want to hide a nav bar item when the user is logged in Firebase using FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser or not. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the tabbar items in a reactive list,
update the list when `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` changes

add or remove items according to your need, and update the reactive widget.

Update procedure depends how you handle state in your app.

For example if you use [Getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get) then you can wrap your `persistent_bootm_nav_bar` into `Obx()/Getx()/GetBuilder()` widget, and keep the items into a global variable or in a parent contrller so that you can access the variable and change its value according to your need